# JPA JPQL query, where object1 = object2

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, java-ee-6, jpql

Query1 (Works fine!!!):

```
em.createQuery(
            "SELECT r FROM Route r WHERE r.start.x = :x"
            , Route.class).setParameter("x", start.getX())
```

Query2 (id really like this one to work!):

```
   em.createQuery(
            "SELECT r FROM Route r WHERE r.start = :x"
            , Route.class).setParameter("x", start)
            .setMaxResults(20)
```

Throws: 
TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing

Route Entity:

```
 @Entity
@XmlRootElement(name="route")

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Route {
private Long id;
private User user;
private Location start;
private Location finish;

public Route() {
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn
public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
public Location getStart() {
    return start;
}

public void setStart(Location start) {
    this.start = start;
}

@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
public Location getFinish() {
    return finish;
}

public void setFinish(Location finish) {
    this.finish = finish;
}
```

}

Location:

```
@Entity
public class Location {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

private double x;

private double y;

public Location() {
}

public Location(double x, double y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

@XmlTransient
public double getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(double x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public double getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setY(double y) {
    this.y = y;
}

public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if ((o instanceof Location)
            && (((Location)o).getX() == this.x)
            && (((Location)o).getY() == this.y))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}
```

}

Comment: what is the `start` variable? Why don't you call the `getX()` method in the second example?

Comment: 'start' is an instance of Location Class received from HTTP POST data ... Eg. same as Location start = new Location("1.0","1.0");    ... I'm not using getx() as I want to be able to test equality of the complex objects ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TransientObjectException was thrown when Class that was instantiated via constructor was being compared with same object of the same Class read from Database. Since Class Route is annotated as @Entity, query has considered the first object to be transient (as it had no @id field set).

Answer (score 1):

The exception doesn't have much to do with the query itself.

It's thrown because, before executing the query, Hibernate flushes the changes that have not been flushed yet. And can't do it because... an object references an unsaved transient instance. So, make sure to save transient instances before executing the query.

Comment: Well, I can see Route and it's start property (as well as all other related entities) are persisted to database before running the query... so I don't see what could probably be that transient instance.

Comment: Step through the code using a debugger, and try to trace all the entities that are attached to managed one but are not made persistent before you execute the query.

Comment: Prior to running the query, I have only one Entity persisted: "User" , User has 1 Route, and Route has a start and finish Location. Once I call  em.getTransaction().commit(); I can see all of them in the database. If I try to call em.flush, jboss will tell me there is no active transactions. So I can call em.close(). And later create new EntityManager to run the query in question. I have a suspicion that  perhaps error is due to Location referenced by "start"(Location class) , which is received from HTTP POST data, and has id = null. But I feel this theory is a bit far fetched.

Comment: I have manually set ID for object received from POST, `start.setId(7777l)` and that has **suppressed** the error. However **equality** between the two objects have not been tested properly. If I build a query `SELECT r FROM Route r` and then go `result.get(0).getStart().equals(start);`  that will return **true**. But `List<Route> routes =  em.createQuery(
                "SELECT r FROM Route r WHERE r.start = :start").setParameter("start", start).getResultList();`  .. will return **empty** List :(

Comment: The Java code compares the objects using the equals() method. The query searches for a route with the same start ID as the ID of the start object passed as argument.

Comment: Turns out JPQL trhows error when trying to compare entity with transient copy of it, and to determine equality considers only primary key (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28613_01/apirefs.1211/e24396/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_equality). I will open another question to check whether a JPQL query exists to compare enitity with a transient object if the same Class more meaningfully.

Comment: No need to open a question. That is not possible with HQL. The closest to what you want is query by example: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria-examples. You have to realize that whatever the way you're querying, it always ends up with a SQL query, executed by the database, which completely ignore what your Java code does.